# Disable asset pipeline for specific files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a few big javascript file, compilation of these files takes a long time! How to disable asset pipeline only for these files? Or maybe exists other solution?

I use rails 4.0.2

Comment: you especially want to minimize and obfuscate these. Without changes there won't be no need for the pipeline to touch them again

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the assets once, so the manifest file is updated. Try to avoid making changes to this file and any js changes should be done in smaller files. When asset precompile takes place, it skips the file with no changes which will reduce the time for asset compile.